# Is it permissible to listen to the Quran while working on a project?

Tags: quran-recitation, reading-quran

I have a particular question regarding the listening and understanding the Quran. Is it permissible to listen to the Quran while working on a project? Will it affect me in any way and should I do it?

Answer (score 6):

When the Quran is being recited/played, you are required to listen to it attentively. Allah (SWT) says:

> So, when the Qur’aan is recited, listen to it, and be silent that you may receive mercy
>
> -[Sura Araf 7:204](http://quran.com/7/204)

This is a very clear command from Allah (SWT) that we should respect, listen and learn from the Quran whenever it is recited, so that we can receive mercy from Him.

And Allah (SWT) knows best.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualykum wa rahmatullahi wa barakat

Anything wrong i write is from me and anything good is from the most high the most merciful Allah swt. Ramadhan Kareem my brother may allah bless you for asking.

Brother it is a good thought and touching that you want to listen to the quran whilst working Mashallah may allah reward you abundantly for all your good deeds and efforts.However brother please give this a thought. The Quran metions "and when you listen to the Quran then you should listen to it attentively". Now the question is whilst you are working on your project are you able to give the recitation your full attention? that is listen to it word for word?. The quran is a message to mankind and a healing and mercy from allah.  Furthermore it is better that you listen to the quran whilst gaining some benefit from it i.e you try to understand what is being recited hence it is good to listen to the version with audio translation or read the translation whilst listening after each ayat this way you are giving each ayat your full attention. If however you feel that listening to the quran is having it on in the background whilst you are engrossed in your project then the recitation would not be listened to attentively hence may be of little benefit but again as i mentioned this is merely my humble opinion and not from a hadith source so may allah forgive me if i have said something to which i have no right. In my humble opinion this would be close to leaving a quran open in the middle of a room without a reciter who happens to glance at it from time to time and i am sure you would agree that to do this would be disrepectful to a blessed book from allah swt. please forgive me if i have said anything that may offend you i have merely tried to give you an explanation based on logic of the qurans ayat re listening to quran being recited. On the other hand it is up to allah to reward good deeds and actions and it may be that he records your wanting to listen as a good action and rewards you as he pleases. Inshallah there are other brothers on here who are more knowledgeable than me. wa alaykum salam wa rahmatullahi wa barakat and ramadan kareem