# Is Eating while watching Islamic T.V Show Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, fiqh, food

I have got used to watching Peace T.V while eating Breakfast, Lunch and dinner is it okay because I am listening  tafsir of Quran and ihadith by scholars while eating please answer with reasons and proofs if any one knows about it Jaza kallah.

Comment: Especially when Qur'an is being recited in the TV, the question is a possible duplicate of [Listening To The Quran While Doing Something Else](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25330/listening-to-the-quran-while-doing-something-else), other than while Qur'an being recited, why do you think it is Haram?

Comment: Some time I think that listeng Quran while doing any type of work is  a type of degrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Quran is being recited, it's best for you to listen and pay attention to it. If you can do that while eating, then there's no problem of multi-tasking.

**وَإِذا قُرِئَ القُرآنُ فَاستَمِعوا لَهُ وَأَنصِتوا لَعَلَّكُم تُرحَمونَ**

**And when the Quran is recited, listen to it and pay attention; that you may receive mercy.** ([Quran 7:204](http://al-quran.info/#7:204))